# how to use bert-tiny using transformers?

Tags: bert

how can I use BERT-tiny .. I tried to load `bert-base-uncased` by this line

```
transformers.AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
```

but how can I use BERT-tiny, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`bert-tiny` model](https://huggingface.co/prajjwal1/bert-tiny) uploaded to the huggingface model repository by user `prajjwal1`. The model card mentions that it uses the checkpoint from the offical Google BERT repository and converted it to pytorch.

```
import transformers

transformers.AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("prajjwal1/bert-tiny")
```

Comment: thanks a lot so if there is another model for BERT i should search for a user who uploads a tiny size of it ? or it is by default there is a tiny model for each BERT model

Comment: This all depends on the model you are using, it's generally best to look at the description of the model to find out what it exactly is.

Comment: thanks a lot but in general does bert better than LSTM or it depends on the size of data ?